# How to destructure data or error from mutation react query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to return error from react-query mutation service hook I've created here

```
const getMutationService = () => {
  return {
    editProfile: async (
      displayName: string,
      privateProfile?: boolean,
    ): Promise<AuthEditMeResponse | undefined> => {
      try {
        const result = await userApi.mePost({
          payload: {
            display_name: displayName,
            _private: privateProfile,
          },
        });
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("User Edit Profile Error", error);
      }
    },
  };
};

const useUserProfile = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const queryService = getQueryService();
  // const { data, isLoading } = useQuery('auth', queryService.login)
  const mutationService = getMutationService();

  const editProfileData = async (
    displayName: string,
    privateProfile?: boolean,
  ): Promise<AuthEditMeResponse | void> => {
    try {
      return await mutationService.editProfile(displayName, privateProfile);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return editProfileData;
};

export default useUserProfile;
```

Right now I am only returning the result, which is the successful result, however the API endpoint I am requesting to also returns error status codes that I must need and use for my front end component.

How can I return isLoading, data, or error from this getMutationService hook i've created? Instead currently its only returning successful responses to my component.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the errors inside the catch blocks, like this:

```
try { //... }
catch(e) {
  throw Error(e);
}
```

And when you invoke the function in your component, inside the catch block you can do something like:

```
try { //... }
catch(e) {
  setError(e.message);
}
```

to show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are catching the error inside the mutation function. When you catch an error, e.g. for logging, it will be transformed into a *resolved* Promise. This has nothing to do with react-query, this is how promises (resp. try/catch with async-await) work.

react-query expects you to return a *rejected* Promise so that it can go into error state. To do this, you can either:

- *not* catch errors in the mutationFn - just let them bubble up to react-query. This is the recommended approach. If you want error logging, use the provided `onError` callback.
- re-throw the error after catching it.